# POST with swift and API

Tags: php, ios, swift

I've a problem when I try to send a POST request to my API on my server, I've followed many many different tutorials but it still doesn't work.
I know than my problem is with the POST request but I can't solve it !
So this is my code in Swift and my API in php : (and yes I've replaced the xxxx by the real IDs in my code)

To sum up server receive the request and for example if I manually enter a pseudo it works, It's really the POST method who doesn't work.. The server doesn't receive the POST parameter

Swift code :

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/academy/test.php")!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var params = ["pseudo":"test"] as Dictionary<String, String>

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                var success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                println("Succes: \(success)")
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()*/
```

PHP Code :

```
$BDD_hote = 'xxxxx';
$BDD_bd = 'xxxxx';
$BDD_utilisateur = 'xxxxx';
$BDD_mot_passe = 'xxxxx';

try{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$BDD_hote.';dbname='.$BDD_bd, $BDD_utilisateur, $BDD_mot_passe);
$bdd->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
}

catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage();
echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
}
$pseudo = addslashes($_POST["pseudo"]);
$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * from users WHERE pseudo='$pseudo'");
$resultArray = array();
$donnees = $req->fetch();
echo json_encode($donnees);
```

Thanks by advance :)

Comment: Please give a bit more detail of "doesn't work"? From the beginning and going on, which step doesn't give you the expected result. Did the server doesn't receive the request at all?

Comment: So the server receive the request and for example if I manually enter a pseudo it works, It's really the POST method who doesn't work.. The server doesn't receive the POST parameter

Comment: By the way, minor point, but see the [`addSlashes` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) which advises that you use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
 let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/academy/test.php")! 
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL)
 request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
 request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
 request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
 let bodyStr:String = "pseudo=test"
 request.HTTPBody = bodyStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) 
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
      data, response, error in

      // Your completion handler code here
 }
 task.resume()
```

You have to encode your data using UTF8 string encoding. If you need to set more than one field&value pairs for request body, you can change the body string, for example, "pseudo=test&language=swift". In fact, I usually create an extension for NSMutableURLRequest and add a method which takes a dictionary as parameter and sets the content of this map(dictionary) as HTTPBody using correct encoding. This may work for you:

```
 extension NSMutableURLRequest {
      func setBodyContent(contentMap: Dictionary<String, String>) {
           var firstOneAdded = false
           let contentKeys:Array<String> = Array(contentMap.keys)
           for contentKey in contentKeys {
                if(!firstOneAdded) {
                     contentBodyAsString += contentKey + "=" + contentMap[contentKey]!
                     firstOneAdded = true
                }
                else {
                     contentBodyAsString += "&" + contentKey + "=" + contentMap[contentKey]! 
                }
           }
           contentBodyAsString = contentBodyAsString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
           self.HTTPBody = contentBodyAsString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
      }
 }
```

And you can use this as:

```
request.setBodyContent(params)
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 15):

As others have pointed out, the encoding of the request is not quite right. Your server code is not expecting JSON request, but rather is using `$_POST` variables (which means that the request should have `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). So that's what you should create. For example in Swift 3 and later:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["somekey" : "valueforkey"]
request.setContent(with: parameters)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }
    // your response parsing code here
}
task.resume()
```

The `setContent` method would take a dictionary of the form `["key1": "foo", "key2" : "bar"]` and populate the `httpBody` with something that looks like `key1=foo&key2=bar`. If you do that, the server will be able to parse the `$_POST` from the request.

```
extension URLRequest {
    /// Set body and header for x-www-form-urlencoded request
    ///
    /// - Parameter parameters: Simple string dictionary of parameters to be encoded in body of request

    mutating func setContent(with parameters: [String: String]) {
        setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let array = parameters.map { entry -> String in
            let key = entry.key.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)!
            let value = entry.value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)!
            return key + "=" + value
        }
        httpBody = array.joined(separator: "&").data(using: .utf8)!
    }
}
```

Note, this also percent-encodes the values (and, just in case, the keys, too), which is critical. While others have advised using `addingPercentEncoding` with `.urlQueryAllowed`, sadly that will not do the job, as it will let certain reserved characters (notably `+`) pass unescaped. Most web services will interpret the `+` as a space, in conformance with [the `x-www-form-urlencoded` spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). So, adapting an approach adopted by Alamofire, I define a character set which will encode values with the various delimiters:

```
extension CharacterSet {

    /// Returns the character set for characters allowed in the individual parameters within a query URL component.
    ///
    /// The query component of a URL is the component immediately following a question mark (?).
    /// For example, in the URL `http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1#jumpLink`, the query
    /// component is `key1=value1`. The individual parameters of that query would be the key `key1`
    /// and its associated value `value1`.
    ///
    /// According to RFC 3986, the set of unreserved characters includes
    ///
    /// `ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"`
    ///
    /// In section 3.4 of the RFC, it further recommends adding `/` and `?` to the list of unescaped characters
    /// for the sake of compatibility with some erroneous implementations, so this routine also allows those
    /// to pass unescaped.

    static var urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@"    // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

        var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)
        return allowed
    }()
}
```

For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28027627/3).

Comment: I got some parameter has '+' character , continuously  failing ....thanks finally got it :)

Answer (score 1):

the following php code is for receiving `application/url+encode` encoded post message. please refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

```
$_POST["pseudo"]
```

and your swift code was sending a `JSON` encoded string data. They are incompatible.

If you don't want to change the php code, in Swift you should send url-encode format message, li:

// UPDATED with corrections from @Rob

```
    var params = ["param1":"value1", "papam2": "value 2"]
    var body = ""
    for (key, value) in params {
        body = body.stringByAppendingString(key)
        body = body.stringByAppendingString("=")
        body = body.stringByAppendingString(value.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body = body.stringByAppendingString("&")
    }
    body = body.substringToIndex(advance(body.startIndex, countElements(body)-1)) // remove the last "&"
    request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work :/ But I can change everything (in PHP or Swift) there isn't any problem :)

Comment: I'm sorry I am no expert in PHP, so from what I understand in your PHP code, the problem is caused by the different format of data between sending and receiving side.

Comment: Don't forget to change `Content-Type` in sender/Swift, set this:     `request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` not the original json one.

Comment: @Rob Yes you are right, I was in a hurry :P all of those corrections are right.