# How to pass json string as parameter in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

How to pass json as parameter string. I have tried by passing json as below but it throws error like `AuthenticateUser: Invalid JSON primitive`.

```
let jsonString = "{\"user\":\"usr\",\"password\":\"pass\"}"

        var urlStr = "http://testserver/AuthenticateUser?data=\(jsonString)"


        var url = NSURL(string: urlStr)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.URL = url
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            {
                (data, response, error) in

                var error: NSError?
                if data != nil {
                    var reply = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    println("reply >> \(reply)")
                }
        }
        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after request initializtion:

```
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: nil, error: &err)
```

Update these lines for json format:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Reference:

[POST with swift and API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008874/post-with-swift-and-api)

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

I brought you answer up to passing json parameter as a string to URL.

```
    var jsonString = "{\"user\":\"usr\",\"password\":\"pass\"}"
    if let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)    
    {
      var error: NSError?
      var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as? NSDictionary
      if error != nil 
      {
        println(error)
      }
      else
      {
        println(json)
      }
      var strUser = json?.valueForKey("user") as String
      var strPassword = json?.valueForKey("password") as String

      println(strUser)
      println(strPassword)

      var url = "http://testserver/AuthenticateUser?data="
      var urlUserParameter = "user="
      var urlPasswordParameter = "&password="
      var appendString = "\(url)\(urlUserParameter)\(strUser)\(urlPasswordParameter)\(strPassword)"
               //OR
      var appendStringOne = url + urlUserParameter + strUser + urlPasswordParameter + strPassword

      println(appendString)
      println(appendStringOne)

    }
```

Explanation

```
  I converted JSON string to NSDictionary.
  Then i get value using key
  Finally i append all these string and now we have URL with parameters.
```